# How to determine what parameters to use for regression or classification?

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn

Im working with CSV file, that has 12 columns. Ten columns are features and two columns represent the results. I made a couple of regression and classification models with Python's scikit-learn lib.

I found out that accuracy varies depending on which features I use and how many parameters I use.

Is there a way to determine what features to use for regression or classification, Is there are way to find out what are the best parameters for my model?

This is the simple code I wrote, it has 3 features and one result, how to determinate what are the best features to use (is it best to use `'par_1'` and `'par_2'` , or just `'par_2'`, `'par_1'` and `'par_3'` , `'par_2`' and `'par_3'` ...):

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression


dic = {'par_1': [10, 30, 11, 19, 28, 33, 23],
       'par_2': [1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2],
       'par_3': [15, 3, 16, 65, 24, 56, 13],
       'outcome': [101, 905, 182, 268, 646, 624, 465]}

df = pd.DataFrame(dic)

variables = df.iloc[:,:-1]
results = df.iloc[:,-1]

print(variables.shape)
print(results.shape)


reg = LinearRegression()
reg.fit(variables, results)

x = reg.predict([[18, 2, 21]])[0]
print(x)
```

Is it a way to get a list of features that I should use?

Comment: In your case, if you have only a couple of variables, you can build all the possible models with all the possible combinations of variables and select the one that minimizes an information criterion, such as AIC. However, you should use domain knowledge to decide this rather then using an automated procedure.

Comment: Well I put the simple case in this question, but what if I have for example 20 features?
Is there a way to get the names of the features that are the best for my model?

Comment: In that case you may be better off using a different model, one that is made for such a purpose, for ex. LASSO regression, which is a form of penalized linear regression that automatically selects the relevant variables.